# How can I sync and organise apps on iPhone from Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, applications

Is there a macOS app to manage and organise apps on iOS? Apple used to 
have this as part of iTunes but since they have dropped that feature there doesn't seem to be any real alternative to manage all those iPhone apps into separate screens and a manageable order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free app [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) to organize apps.

Once the device is connected, right-click > Modify > Home Screen Layout:

[image]

Then you can manipulate the apps, folders and home screens as you could in iTunes.

[image]

Configurator has plenty of of neat features, especially if you manage other people's iOS devices.

Comment: Looking at Apple Configurator it should do the job but the app is super buggy and seems less fit for purpose. It would be great to see what other options are available.

Comment: This seems to only manage a maximum of 4 screens. I have seven. Is there any way to make this silly subfeature scroll over?

Comment: I haven't used AC2 for this purpose for a while. The iOS interface for managing iDevice screens has improved since 2018, and I've found it easier to manage my own devices that way. Professionally we use JAMF for this purpose on our institutional iPad fleet, and it has an even greater functionality for hiding apps we don't want accessible.